# GroupBy and pie plot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data. Mark - 5 unique values , name - 200+ persons, group - 10 values, meeting - 50 values, present - max value is 20. Each meeting consists of presentations.
Small example:

```
data = [
 ['A', 'Frodo', 'group_1', 1, 1],
 ['A', 'Sam', 'group_2', 1, 1],
 ['N', 'Frodo', 'group_1', 1, 2],
 ['A', 'Sam', 'group_2', 1, 2],
 ['Z', 'Frodo', 'group_1', 1, 3],
 ['N', 'Sam', 'group_2', 1, 3],
 ['M', 'Frodo', 'group_1', 1, 4],
 ['Z', 'Sam', 'group_2', 1, 4],
 ['O', 'Frodo', 'group_1', 1, 5],
 ['A', 'Sam', 'group_2', 1, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['mark', 'name', 'group', 'meeting', 'present'])
```

I would like to get a pie graph for each group, where each person in it will be plotted his grades 'N' as a percentage of the rest of the grades.
As a title, I would like the name of the group, and each has pie plot the name of the person, and inside the graph there are numbers in percent.

```
plot_df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['name', 'group'])['mark'].value_counts()).rename(columns={'mark':'mark_count'})
plot_df.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='pie', stacked=True, subplots=True, figsize = (7,7), legend=False);
```

I counted the number of marks for each person in the group. I don't know how to get the percentage. I also build a graph for each person, but I don’t know how to group by the graphs by groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`autopct=`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html) for a simple percentage display. I think it's an effect of the data structure, but you'll see an extra 0% display.

```
plot_df.unstack(level=0).plot(
    kind='pie',
    stacked=True,
    subplots=True,
    autopct='%1.1f%%',
    figsize=(7, 7),
    legend=False,
    )
```

[image]